# Unexpected 'else' on $_GET request

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, get

I've been working on this code awhile, the error thrown just doesn't make any sense, I've googled around but I just can't find a working solution, or anyone to explain why so I can prevent it in the future.

This error is thrown:

> **Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /home/cabox/workspace/up/frontend/pages/settings.php on line 139

Line 139 is the first `else` statement:

```
if (isset($_GET['act'])) {
        $act = $_GET['act'];
        $arr = array('delete');
        $arr2 = array('blacklist');
        $arr3 = array('unblacklist');
        if (in_array($act, $arr)) {
                $de = $odb->prepare("DELETE FROM login_attempts WHERE id = :i");
                $de->execute(array(":i" => $tid));
                echo '<div class="alert alert-success">log deleted.  </div><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=settings.php">';
                break;
            }else{
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Something went wrong, please try again</div>';
            }
        }else{
        }
        if (in_array($act, $arr2)) {
            echo 'div class="alert alert-danger">blacklist</div>';
        }else{
            $getblack = $_GET['ip'];
            $de2 = $odb->prepare("INSERT INTO blacklist VALUES(null, :ip)");
            $de2 = $odb->execute(array(":ip" => $getblack));
        }else{
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Something went wrong, please try again</div>';
        }
}
```

Comment: you cant have 2 elses in a row its illogical

Comment: Your indentation is completely out of control here.

Comment: `if`, `else` and `also else`?

Comment: There are all sorts of issues here, use a decent code editor that shows syntax highlighting and you'll see all the issues

Comment: On the bright side, at least you are parameterizing your queries!